# Configuring Gitlab through Apache with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, gitlab

i want to use GitLab through apache with ssl. I followed [this](https://oliversmith.io/technology/2014/07/18/reverse-proxying-gitlab-with-apache-and-ssl/) guide but i still get a 503 Service Unavailable message.

I have installed GitLab as described in the [instruction](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604) from GitLab.

My gitlab.rb configuration looks like the file in the guide:

`external_url 'https://domain:4443'
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificateBundle.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificate.key"`

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain
    ServerAlias domain

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificate.key
    SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/gitlab/tls/IntermediateCertificate.crt
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / https://domain:4443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://domain/

    Header edit Location ^http://domain/ https://domain/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

</VirtualHost>
```

Did i forget something?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution for my problem (maybe others struggling with the same thing)

My gitlab.rb config file:

```
external_url 'https://domain'
nginx['listen_address'] = 'localhost'
nginx['listen_port'] = 8888
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

And my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain
    ServerAlias domain
    ServerAdmin mail

    RequestHeader set Host "domain"
    RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Ssl on
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/gitlab/tls/SignedCertificate.key
    SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/gitlab/tls/IntermediateCertificate.crt
    SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
</VirtualHost>
```

For me GitLab is now working with TLS over apache